# Android emulator shows home screen upside down mirrored and locked (why?)

Tags: android, emulation, homescreen

I am starting the emulator from the command line to try and speed it up a little, with these arguments:

emulator -avd foo_hvga2 -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim

Here is a verbose dump of the emulator output.... thank you for any clues

emulator -avd foo_hvga2 -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -verbose -debug all -show-kernel

```
emulator: found SDK root at /Users/foobear/android-sdks
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.ini
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='target' VALUE='android-16'
emulator:    2: KEY='path' VALUE='/Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd'
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.ini: parsing finished
emulator: virtual device content at /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/config.ini
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/config.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='160'
emulator:    2: KEY='skin.name' VALUE='HVGA'
emulator:    3: KEY='skin.path' VALUE='platforms/android-16/skins/HVGA'
emulator:    4: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='arm'
emulator:    5: KEY='abi.type' VALUE='armeabi-v7a'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.cpu.model' VALUE='cortex-a8'
emulator:    7: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='48'
emulator:    8: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='512'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   10: KEY='image.sysdir.1' VALUE='system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/'
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/config.ini: parsing finished
emulator: using core hw config path: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found target field in root AVD .ini file: 'android-16'
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 16
emulator:     found image search path: system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/
emulator: found a total of 1 search paths for this AVD
emulator: found skin 'HVGA' in directory: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Users/foobear/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/skins
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
emulator: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    2: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='160'
emulator:    3: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='512'
emulator:    4: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='48'
emulator: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini: parsing finished
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CALL to F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HANGUP to F4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HOME to HOME
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_BACK to ESCAPE
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to PAGEUP
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to Shift-F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to PAGEDOWN
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_POWER to F7
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_SEARCH to F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to KEYPAD_PLUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Ctrl-F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to KEYPAD_MINUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Ctrl-F6
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_NETWORK to F8
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACING to F9
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN to Alt-ENTER
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER to KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_UP to KEYPAD_8
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT to KEYPAD_4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT to KEYPAD_6
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN to KEYPAD_2
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACKBALL to F6
emulator: adding binding SHOW_TRACKBALL to DELETE
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to KEYPAD_7
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Ctrl-F11
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to KEYPAD_9
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Ctrl-F12
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_UP to KEYPAD_MULTIPLY
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_DOWN to KEYPAD_DIVIDE
emulator: keyset loaded from: /Users/foobear/.android/default.keyset
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='window.x' VALUE='380'
emulator:    2: KEY='window.y' VALUE='52'
emulator:    3: KEY='uuid' VALUE='1342389488653'
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing finished
emulator: trying to load skin file '/Users/foobear/android-sdks/platforms/android-16/skins/HVGA/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: found kernel-qemu in search dir: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
emulator: found ramdisk.img in search dir: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
emulator: found system.img in search dir: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/
emulator: Using initial system image: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

emulator:     no qwerty2.kcm in search dir: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing as .ini file
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing finished
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 320
  hw.lcd.height = 480
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0
  disk.ramdisk.path = /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = foo_hvga2
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/Users/foobear/android-sdks/tools/emulator-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-cpu-delay"
emulator: argv[02] = "0"
emulator: argv[03] = "-show-kernel"
emulator: argv[04] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[05] = "/Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /Users/foobear/android-sdks/tools/emulator-arm -cpu-delay 0 -show-kernel -android-hw /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service hw-control
emulator: android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='arm'
emulator:    2: KEY='hw.cpu.model' VALUE='cortex-a8'
emulator:    3: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='512'
emulator:    4: KEY='hw.screen' VALUE='touch'
emulator:    5: KEY='hw.mainKeys' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.trackBall' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    7: KEY='hw.keyboard' VALUE='no'
emulator:    8: KEY='hw.keyboard.lid' VALUE='no'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='qwerty2'
emulator:   10: KEY='hw.dPad' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   11: KEY='hw.gsmModem' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   12: KEY='hw.gps' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   13: KEY='hw.battery' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   14: KEY='hw.accelerometer' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   15: KEY='hw.audioInput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   16: KEY='hw.audioOutput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   17: KEY='hw.sdCard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   18: KEY='disk.cachePartition' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   19: KEY='disk.cachePartition.path' VALUE='/Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/cache.img'
emulator:   20: KEY='disk.cachePartition.size' VALUE='66m'
emulator:   21: KEY='hw.lcd.width' VALUE='320'
emulator:   22: KEY='hw.lcd.height' VALUE='480'
emulator:   23: KEY='hw.lcd.depth' VALUE='16'
emulator:   24: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='160'
emulator:   25: KEY='hw.lcd.backlight' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   26: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   27: KEY='hw.camera.back' VALUE='emulated'
emulator:   28: KEY='hw.camera.front' VALUE='none'
emulator:   29: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='48'
emulator:   30: KEY='hw.sensors.proximity' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   31: KEY='hw.sensors.magnetic_field' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   32: KEY='hw.sensors.orientation' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   33: KEY='hw.sensors.temperature' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   34: KEY='kernel.path' VALUE='/Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//kernel-qemu'
emulator:   35: KEY='kernel.parameters' VALUE='android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0'
emulator:   36: KEY='disk.ramdisk.path' VALUE='/Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//ramdisk.img'
emulator:   37: KEY='disk.systemPartition.initPath' VALUE='/Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//system.img'
emulator:   38: KEY='disk.systemPartition.size' VALUE='200m'
emulator:   39: KEY='disk.dataPartition.path' VALUE='/Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/userdata-qemu.img'
emulator:   40: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='200m'
emulator:   41: KEY='avd.name' VALUE='foo_hvga2'
emulator: /Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing finished
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=/Users/foobear/android-sdks/system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-foobear/emulator-lNlrjC
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gsm
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gps
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service camera
emulator: android_camera_service_init: Registered 'camera' qemud service
emulator: IP address of your DNS(s): 75.75.75.75, 75.75.76.76
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Users/foobear/.android/avd/foo_hvga2.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=1 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 ndns=2
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
2012-07-15 15:55:14.148 emulator-arm[12082:80b] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service sensors
emulator: android_hw_sensors_init: sensors qemud service initialized
serial0 console^M
emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Using config file: /Users/foobear/.android/modem-nv-ram-5554
Setting value of oper_name_index to 2 (2)Setting value of selection_mode to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_index to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_count to 2 (2)Setting value of in_ecbm to 0 (0)Setting value of prl_version to 0 (0)Setting value of preferred_mode to 15 (15)Setting value of cdma_subscription_source to 1 (1)Setting value of cdma_roaming_pref to 2 (2)emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /Users/foobear/android-sdks/tools/ddms ping emulator 20.0 "Intel Inc." "Intel GMA X3100 OpenGL Engine" "2.0 APPLE-1.6.36"
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 13
Uncompressing Linux................................................................................................. done, booting the kernel.^M
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:167: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
 bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Linux version 2.6.29-gc497e41 (kroot@kennyroot.mtv.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #2 Thu Dec 8 15:07:43 PST 2011
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc080] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387f
CPU: VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
Machine: Goldfish
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
Kernel command line: qemu.gles=1 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 ndns=2
Unknown boot option `qemu.gles=1': ignoring
Unknown boot option `android.qemud=ttyS1': ignoring
Unknown boot option `android.checkjni=1': ignoring
Unknown boot option `android.bootanim=0': ignoring
PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 11, 8192 bytes)
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Memory: 512MB = 512MB total
Memory: 515712KB available (2756K code, 683K data, 108K init)
Calibrating delay loop... 211.35 BogoMIPS (lpj=1056768)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
Initializing cgroup subsys debug
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
net_namespace: 716 bytes
NET: Registered protocol family 16
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)
TCP reno registered
NET: Registered protocol family 1
checking if image is initramfs... it is
Freeing initrd memory: 160K
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_interrupt_controller at ff000000 irq -1
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_device_bus at ff001000 irq 1
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_timer at ff003000 irq 3
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_rtc at ff010000 irq 10
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff002000 irq 4
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff011000 irq 11
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff012000 irq 12
goldfish_new_pdev smc91x at ff013000 irq 13
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_fb at ff014000 irq 14
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_audio at ff004000 irq 15
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_memlog at ff006000 irq -1
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-battery at ff015000 irq 16
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_events at ff016000 irq 17
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_nand at ff017000 irq -1
goldfish_new_pdev qemu_pipe at ff018000 irq 18
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-switch at ff01a000 irq 19
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-switch at ff01b000 irq 20
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_interrupt_controller
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_device_bus
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_timer
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_rtc
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
goldfish_pdev_worker registered smc91x
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_fb
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_audio
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_memlog
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-battery
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_events
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_nand
goldfish_pdev_worker registered qemu_pipe
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-switch
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-switch
ashmem: initialized
Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
yaffs Dec  8 2011 15:06:54 Installing.
msgmni has been set to 1008
alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered (default)
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered
allocating frame buffer 320 * 480, got ffa00000
console [ttyS0] enabled
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
nbd: registered device at major 43
goldfish_audio_probe
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_SET_WRITE_BUFFER_1 1f9e0000
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_SET_WRITE_BUFFER_2 1f9e4000
emulator: goldfish_audio_read: AUDIO_READ_SUPPORTED returns 1
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_SET_READ_BUFFER 1f9e8000
tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
smc91x.c: v1.1, sep 22 2004 by Nicolas Pitre <nico@cam.org>
eth0 (smc91x): not using net_device_ops yet
eth0: SMC91C11xFD (rev 1) at e080c000 IRQ 13 [nowait]
eth0: Ethernet addr: 52:54:00:12:34:56
goldfish nand dev0: size c200000, page 2048, extra 64, erase 131072
goldfish nand dev1: size c200000, page 2048, extra 64, erase 131072
goldfish nand dev2: size 4000000, page 2048, extra 64, erase 131072
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
*** events probe ***
events_probe() addr=0xe0814000 irq=17
events_probe() keymap=qwerty2
input: qwerty2 as /devices/virtual/input/input0
goldfish_rtc goldfish_rtc: rtc core: registered goldfish_rtc as rtc0
device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.14.0-ioctl (2008-04-23) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
logger: created 64K log 'log_main'
logger: created 256K log 'log_events'
logger: created 64K log 'log_radio'
TCP cubic registered
NET: Registered protocol family 10
IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8 Ben Greear <greearb@candelatech.com>
All bugs added by David S. Miller <davem@redhat.com>
FP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 0
goldfish_rtc goldfish_rtc: setting system clock to 2012-07-15 22:55:15 UTC (1342392915)
Freeing init memory: 108K
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
yaffs: dev is 32505856 name is "mtdblock0"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.0, "mtdblock0"
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 13
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused

yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
save exit: isCheckpointed 1
yaffs: dev is 32505857 name is "mtdblock1"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.1, "mtdblock1"
```

Comment: it will work normally but extremely slow...
are there any possibilities to fix it without disabling GPU emulation ?

Comment: Having the same prob: if I disable it, it's completely unusable

Comment: I have also faced a problem when you cannot run emulator at all (it shuts down with an exception). The solution for me was to disconnect external display. current model - Macbook pro 13", not retina with Intel Graphics HD 4000, Mid 2012.

Damn it, so many errors appear in the latest model of macbook. I really regret selling mid 2010 model. Also it was faster by far due to SSD.

Comment: what do you mean by disconnecting external display?

Comment: I mean disconnecting monitor that is connected to a macbook. (unplug a miniDisplay cable/adapter)

Comment: I'm not using any external display

Comment: @noloman anyway it is a solution if you cannot run emulator at all (even with hw.gpu.enabled off)

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a bug with hardware GPU emulation. (You have `hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='yes'` in your logs, which means this feature is enabled.)

Disable "GPU emulation" in your AVD settings and things should work normally.

Comment: cool, thank you.  I got around it by just closing Eclipse and starting a new project, rebooting everything, etc.  I'll keep this in mind next time I see it happen

Answer (score 7):

After I installed the Android SDK Tools 21.1 rc (in Preview Channel), the emulator with host GPU enabled works great now (fast and never upside-down).

Just launch Android SDK Manager and enable the preview channel in the settings dialog.

Comment: This is the only real answer to Android Emulator problems on retina screens.

Comment: Disabling Host GPU makes emulator barely usable. But this! This is the answer :)